# Is there a PureText equivalent on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I use a little utility called [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) under Windows to copy & paste formatted content as pure text.  Is there an equivalent to this for Linux users (specifically Ubuntu)?  I hope to be switching in a couple of weeks.   !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a definite answer to your question, as I never really felt the need for something similar.

In ubuntu I commonly use `ctrl-shift-v` do do special pastes (including "paste as simple text").

I just thought to mention it, in case you didn't know about this possibility.